# Error when trying to delete column that was part of dropped unique constraint

Tags: h2

I'm trying to remove a column from a table.

Since that column is part of a unique constraint, I

- first drop the constraint
- and then try to drop the column

But I get: `Column may be referenced by "PUBLIC.UNIQUE_MYTABLE_INDEX_7";`, with is the 'UNIQUE_INDEX_NAME' of the constraint that i previously just deleted by name.

The problem occurs for at least 2 different tables in my database.

I tried splitting this into 2 steps. First dropping the unique constraint, then checking that the constraint is gone. There is no constraint with id 'UNIQUE_MYTABLE_INDEX_7' in the db anymore. But then in step 2, when I try to drop the column, I still get the same error about that id, even thought it does not exist anymore in the database.

Using H2 1.4.196.

I cannot reproduce it with a new test database. Also note that in this example, the error reports the constraint name, and not the unique index name of the constraint:

```
public class Test
{
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
  {
    Connection c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:h2:~/Desktop/test", "test", "test");
    Statement s = c.createStatement();

    s.executeUpdate("DROP TABLE mytable IF EXISTS;");

    String sql = "";
    sql += "CREATE TABLE mytable (";
    sql += "    id                 BIGINT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY";
    sql += "  , a                  BIGINT";
    sql += "  , b                  BIGINT";
    sql += ");";
    s.executeUpdate(sql);

    s.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO mytable VALUES(1, 2, 3);");
    s.executeUpdate("ALTER TABLE mytable ADD CONSTRAINT UNIQUE_myconstraint UNIQUE(a, b);");

    //    s.executeUpdate("ALTER TABLE mytable DROP CONSTRAINT UNIQUE_myconstraint;");
    s.executeUpdate("ALTER TABLE mytable DROP COLUMN a;");
  }
}
```